Define a custom attribute in SVG file
I am batch-generating SVG files from an existing SVG, with a custom variant of a script called exportlayers.py. In order not to re-generate an SVG which already exists, I'd like to save an attribute in the files I generate giving some description of their contents, so when asked to generate a SVG under the same file name, again I can check whether the contents are up-to-date or not.
What is the good way to add such a custom property in an SVG file? I tried adding one in the first element, tagged "svg", adding some custom attribute (named "exportLayers:show"), but inkview complains that Namespace prefix exportLayers for show on svg is not defined.
Can I ignore this error? Is it because the svg element is codified, should I create a new one?
EDIT
With @RobertLongson help, I have reached this:
<svg ...
xmlns:exportLayers="urn:exportLayers:1" 
exportLayers:show="['A']" 
exportLayers:hide="['B']">

I don't get any complain from inkview, for me issue is solved but I welcome further comments on whether this is appropriate/robust.

Define your own namespace.

@RobertLongson: can you guide me towards that? I read that amounts to adding in the "svg" element an xlmns:prefix="URI" attribute. Can I pick this "exportLayers" prefix, and will a rubbish URL in the URI field do...?

That's exactly how you do it. Doesn't need to be a url though it can be anything you like.

What is an example of the value of the attribute and what is it used for? Maybe you could just use the <title> element in SVG.

You should delete that last section in your question and write it as an answer instead.

SVG is XML format and must meet the XML requirements and schema.  Namespaces in XML should always be followed so errors do not occur when file is read.  You are violating the schema which means you file contains errors.

The spec has some guidance on how to integrate foreign content and private data into SVG content.
